# how to create json string in swift and send it to server

Tags: json, swift

I want to create a json string and send it to server. I want to send the JSON I mentioned with the Alamofire library. now the question is how can I create this json string in swift programing?

```
{"Notification":
[
{"id":"15","TableName":"HadafShakhsi","RowId":"148424-1","Operation":"2","StoreName":"SelectHadafShakhsi","isFirst":"1"}
]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post, what you have tried yet? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: NSJONSerialization? What have you tried?

Comment: NSJONSerialization? Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
   "Notification": [

    "id": "15",
  ..........
  ......


] 
    ]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://server.com", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
        print(response)
        print(JSON)
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function prepareforObject as

```
func prepareObjects(dict : Dictionary<String, Any> ) -> [String: AnyObject] {

        var dictParameters = [String: AnyObject]()
        for (key, value) in dict {
            dictParameters[key] = "\(value)" as AnyObject?
        }

        return dictParameters
    }
```

and then call Alamofire as

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://server.com", parameters: prepareforObject(parameters), encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
        print(response)
        print(JSON)
        print(error)
    }
```